# unable to uninstall youtube-dl using brew uninstall command?`

Tags: command-line, homebrew

```
brew uninstall youtube-dl 

Warning: Unexpected method 'arch' called on Cask visual-studio-code. 

Follow the instructions here:   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs Error: Cask 'visual-studio-code' definition is 

invalid: invalid 'sha256' value: {:arm=>"35a0732beac80cc8a0c706832b514bf2e5b6029b391735f95d73f6b17da5d7c0", :intel=>"86c72ed8da5ad35e4d4d72ddc1c32b5237b6c043a1d7d7195f3ade2587e881e0"} 

ethen@yichens-mbp-2 .config %
```

I have visual-studio-code installed on my computer, but I don't understand where that has to do with anything. (it is mentioned in the log for no reason at all)

update:

brew config result:

```
brew config HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.5.6 
ORIGIN:https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/brew.git 
HEAD:0b030b74e2ac518bd0bc4158f96c449198f9957f 
Last commit: 8 months ago 
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core 
Core tap HEAD: 588c31e556d1cffffc41adcf121c3a154af4991e 
Core tap last commit: 7 months ago  
Core tap branch: master 
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew 
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: [] 
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 10 
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.10 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby 
CPU: 10-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm 
Clang: 14.0.0 build 1400 
Git: 2.37.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git 
Curl: 7.86.0 => /usr/bin/curl 
macOS: 13.2.1-arm64 
CLT: 14.2.0.0.1.1668646533 
Xcode: N/A Rosetta 2: false
```

Comment: Post the results to `brew config`

Comment: @nicepen hi, kindly see the update

Comment: working on your fix now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your origin is bad. It should be "ORIGIN: [https://github.com/Homebrew/brew"](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew%22). Try `brew update -reset` and if that doesn't straighten it out then try:

```
git -C $(brew --repo) remote set-url origin https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Update:

If needed try the instructions here: https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues#cask---checksum-does-not-match

> Cask - checksum does not match First, check if the problem was with
> your download. Delete the downloaded file (its location will be
> pointed out in the error message) and try again.
>
> If the problem persists, the cask must be outdated. It’ll likely need
> a new version, but it’s possible the version has remained the same
> (this happens occasionally when the vendor updates the app in-place).
>
> 1. Go to the vendor’s website (brew home <cask_name>).
> 2. Find out what the latest version is. It may be expressed in the URL used to download it.
> 3. Take a look at the cask’s version (brew info <cask_name>) and verify it is indeed outdated. If so, it will need to be updated.
>
> Help us by
> submitting a fix. If you get stumped, open an issue explaining your
> steps so far and where you’re having trouble.

Comment: Hi. thank you so much for replying. I think what causes confusion here is I live in China, and the official brew origin is very slow to reach, so I read on the internet and set up a mirrow  run by a university here.

Comment: Your last commits are pretty old and your vs code isn't passing it's checksum. If the steps listed above from "common issues" doesn't help then I'd check to see if that origin is still good.

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting this error because you have an issue with the visual-studio-code package in Homebrew Cask. Most likely, when you attempt to uninstall any package, it does some check on all packages, which fails on Visual Studio Code.

First, start by trying to clear any errors inside Brew with the following commands.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew doctor
```

Then try uninstalling again with

```
brew uninstall youtube-dl
```

If that doesn't work, I recommend removing Visual Studio Code to see if that clears the error. You can reinstall it after youtube-dl is removed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your speedy response. Is it because my visual studio is "fake" since the sha256 does not match?

Comment: I think your cask info is bad. See my answer.